# Populating PDF fields from a database

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file (not created by me - I have no control over the design etc.) which allows users to fill in some form fields in Adobe Reader and save the result. I want to automate the process of populating the fields, using the following steps:

1. Fetch data from database.
2. Open PDF template.
3. Populate form fields with data.
4. Save modified file to a separate location on disk.
5. Lock modified file so that the form fields can no longer be edited.
6. Send file to user.

I'm happy to use PHP, Perl, Python or Java to do steps 2-5 (in descending order of preference), but whatever I use has to work under Linux (i.e. it mustn't rely on libraries which are only available on Windows for example).

The end result should be a PDF which the average user can open and print, but not modify (I'm sure advanced users could find a way to do so, but I accept that I can't guarantee complete security against modification). I don't want to change the structure of the PDF, merely populate the form fields.

Is there a standard piece of software for doing this? I've seen mentions of FDF Toolkit, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what I want and whether it will allow me to lock the file afterwards, and whether what I want to do fits in with the EULA.

Edit: Final answer is to use iText (as suggested by Mark Storer) but to implement it as a web service which allows you to pass in an array of form field names and values and the PDF file 'template'. The web service will be open source (and available on GitHub once I've written it), as per the AGPL, but anything connecting to it won't have to be.

Comment: Code is now available on GitHub: https://github.com/pwaring/FormFillFlatten

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Filling

Any number of different libraries can fill in field values.  I'm partial to iText (java) or iTextSharp (c#).  I wrote one in Java a number of years ago.  It's not that hard).  There are lots.  Search SO, you'll find 'em.

#### Locking

There are a couple different levels of "lock the fields".

- Each field has a "read only" flag.  This is pretty much a courtesy as far as other libraries capable of setting field values are concerned.  In fact, it's generally considered to mean "the ui cannot make changes".  Form script can, regardless.
- Form flattening: Draw the fields directly into the page and removing all the interactivity.

Each one has pros and cons.

**Flag**: None too secure.  Form data still easily accessible.  Scrolling fields still scroll.
**Flattening**: Pretty much the exact opposite.  It's harder to modify (though far from impossile). The form data can only be extracted via text extraction (which is hard, but becoming increasingly common).  List & text fields that contain more stuff than is visible will no longer scroll.

The ability to flatten forms is relatively rare.  Again, iText can do it (as can iTextSharp), but I'm not aware of any other third party libraries that can... I'm sure they exist, I just can't name them off the top of my head.

Comment: +1 I have used iTextSharp for this purpose. Keep in mind though that you may need intimate knowledge of the PDF form because fillable fields are sometimes not in the order you expect.

Comment: How much intimate knowledge would I need? I know what the PDF looks like and I assume each form field has some kind of name/identifier.

I think flattening is the only option, and I'm not fussed about scrolling because these documents will probably be printed by the end user anyway.

Comment: Oh hang on, iText uses the Affero GPL, and I can't use that in our web application as it would presumably mean releasing the source code. :( (yes there are commercial licences, but the fact that you have to ask how much they cost suggests they are expensive).

Comment: Several thousand USD, yes.  Older versions of iText[Sharp] were released under MPL/LGPL.  In a pinch you can use them, but there's no fork/maintenance.

Comment: I checked some tutorial but they are using VS 2005 which doesn't load up in my 2012. Is there an updated tutorials on how to do this? I am having the issue as the OP. I would like to populate a PDF based on some database table column.