# CakePHP populate PDF Certificates using preset PDF templates and same data sent to the "view" action?

Tags: cakephp, pdf-generation, cakephp-2.0, tcpdf

I am looking for very similar requirements as in [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475232/populating-pdf-fields-from-a-database) but in cakePHP 2.0 instead!

I have different PDF templates for different types of certificates. The PDF templates are pretty much like PDF Forms with editable fields. Fields are the same among all certificates except  slight design differences.

Right now, I can view these fields on the browser using the typical view.ctp of the related controller.

**What I am looking for**, is to add a button "**View in PDF**" in same "view.ctp" to populate same data into the fields of the related PDF template.

Unfortunately, [CakePDF](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) is for CakePHP 2.1+ and I am stuck with 2.0 version (for now at least).

*Update: is there a way CakePDF can be tweaked to work with CakePHP 2.0??

[TCPDF Tutorial](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf) Didn't work with me at all (populated blank pages). And I didn't comprehend where exactly I need to modify to create my PDF templates. (either it assumes knowledge/experience I don't have, or it lacks proper documentation).

I tried [How to create PDF helper with TCPDF](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-create-pdf-helper-with-tcpdf) tutorial and I managed (with [modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728200/creating-pdf-helper-for-cakephp-2-0-using-tcpdf)) to get pdf files to be downloaded using available tcpdf examples. But I still don't know exactly how to custom those pdf files to my needs. Not mentioning that I need to view the files rather than download them.

I feel above tutorials deal with different PDF-related needs but not exactly what I am looking for. Or I might need a proper guidance on how to approach my goals through the same tutorials above?!

Answer (score 1):

I've used DomPDF to generate PDFs from CakePHP pages.  The downside is that DomPDF doesn't understand a lot of CSS.  Here's a page that explains one way to do it:  http://www.syahzul.com/cakephp/how-to-generate-pdf-in-cakephp-2-x-with-dompdf/  They mention 2.2 specifically, but the library itself will work in 2.0, since DomPDF is an independent library.  How you go about hooking it up in Cake could be slightly different.

One last thing that page didn't mention is that using DomPDF to generate webpages from markup (as used in the example) rather than from a URL has problems if you try to include exterior files like css or images using a relative paths.  You have to use absolute paths in your website's directory structure instead.  Example for including styles.css from the css folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP; ?>webroot/css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: I read a lot about DomPDF issues and limitations. People have more success with tcpdf. And I would rather stick with tcpdf or something that is proven to be better.